# index.js for npm package for browser transpiled with babel

Tags: javascript, npm, ecmascript-6

Having some problems figuring out how to completely create and setup an npm package that I want to publish for use in browser environments.

I believe I'm missing some info on how to generate the index file.

I have the `testpackage` linked into my test application via `npm link` in both project directories. My test application is setup with webpack and babel and is written in es6, so using `import` and `export`.

The source is written in es6 and being transpiled via babel. Here's the relevant section of the `package.json` with the build command:

```
{
  "name": "testpackage",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "babel src --out-dir dist",
    "lint": "eslint ."
  },
  "dependencies": {},
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1"
  }
}
```

I've tried creating the `index.js` file in two ways, first via es6 and again as `module.exports` but neither is working.

```
// es6 index.js in testpackage
import store from './dist/store';
import attach from './dist/attach';

export {store, attach};
```

--

```
// index.js with modules.exports
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  store: require(path.resolve(__dirname, './dist/store')),
  attach: require(path.resolve(__dirname, './dist/attach'))
}
```

In this es6 first case, the test application that I'm importing `testpackage` into isn't finding `dist`.

`Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'dist/store' in '/usr/local/apps/testpackage'`

In the second case, the code is clearly meant to run via node, but instead is just being loaded directly into the browser. I was thinking the webpack + babel transpiling step in the test app should run this, but its not.

What about this setup am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Finally figured this out. The first approach was right. I needed to create an es6 index.js in the src directory that imports and exports the other files. Then babel transpiles this into the /dist directory, and `main` in package.json is pointed to /dist/index. The problem was that I didn't have the index being transpiled.